# I have installed visual studio and installed salesforce extension pack but cant create project

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

When i was trying to create project getting error:

Command 'SFDX: Create Project' resulted in an error (command 'sfdx.force.project.create' not found) .

I already have installed updated salesforce cli

Answer (score 0):

Its not dot `.` . It should be colon `:` .

```
cd path/to/your/sfdx/projects sfdx force:project:create --projectname MyLWC cd MyLWC
```

And try the below scenario too -

Once you have sfdx cli installed, you can test it by opening the command window and typing sfdx and then pressing enter you should get the result similar to the one given in the below image:-

[image: ][1]]

If this not works then you have to set sfdx CLI path in the environment variable

From here you can take help if you want to know how to set environment variables - https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml

Comment: The internal command in VS Code uses `.`, not `:` (e.g. `sfdx.force.project.create` is a command that executes `sfdx force:project:create`).

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you've installed the Salesforce CLI (DX), the Extension Bundle, and VS Code, you may simply need to restart your computer. Failing that, uninstall the Extension Bundle, then reinstall it; one of its dependencies may have failed to install correctly.